# Como usar readlines() en phyton

Tags: python

He intentado usar el método readlines() de python para leer de un fichero txt, todo parece bien porque el mismo código trabaja bien en la consola de eclipse, pero cuando subo el el archivo al sitio que me está dando hosting me sale el error

Incomplete response received from application

Y sé que es el método readlines porque cuando no lo uso la aplicación no me da ese error.
Entonces mi duda es si pudiera ser el servidor del sitio que me da hosting, pues como dije en la consola de eclipse me da muy bien

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
class FicherosTexto:
    def __init__(self, nombreFichero):
        self.nombreFichero = nombreFichero

    def titulosLibrosBiblia(self):
        archivo = open(self.nombreFichero, "r")
        contenido = archivo.readlines()
        misTitulos = []
        for titulo in contenido:
            misTitulos.append(titulo)
        archivo.close()
        return misTitulos
```

Comment: `readlines()` está correctamente usado. Creo que tu problema no está relacionado con `readlines()`, sino con la respuesta HTTP que estás generando a partir de los datos `misTitulos`. Sería necesario conocer en qué framework estás trabajando y cómo es la función que responde a la petición, pues esa es la que está enviando una respuesta incompleta. Es posible también que el fichero al que intentas acceder no exista (o esté en otra ruta, o no tenga los permisos adecuados) y eso cause una excepción que aborte la petición.

Comment: En cualquier caso, si crees que `readlines()` es el problema, realmente no necesitas usarlo. Una vez abierto el archivo puedes hacer `for titulo in archivo:`, y eso iterará línea a línea por el contenido del archivo (leyendo automáticamente una línea de cada vez)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta abulafia. Ya encontré la solución, probando y probando, quitando y poniendo código, sin saber como depurar pues me daba el error cuando la desplegaba en el servidor del hosting. Bueno, el problema no era readlines(), era archivo = open(self.nombreFichero, "r"), tenía que ver con el encoding, no tengo mucha experiencia en esto pero parece que el servidor del hosting ve diferente esos txt a mi PC personal, no sé explicar con palabras técnicas, la cuestion es que funcionó así:  archivo = open("librostxt/titulolibrosbiblia.txt", encoding='windows-1252')

Comment: readlines() está correctamente usado. El problema quizás se relaciona con la respuesta HTTP que generas.